# How to output the digits of a number as an integer, which the digits can exact divide the another number?

Tags: c, recursion

I have to output the digits of a number as an integer, which the digits of this number can exact divide another number with the function `unsigned deldigits(unsigned num, unsigned short div)`
For example, if `num=1234; div=2`, then digits `1%2=1 (then i need the digit 1)`, `2%2=0(take out)`, `3%2=1 (then i need the digit 3)`, `4%2=0 (take out)`, so the output must be `13`as an integer.

Loop, globe/static variable, array or pointer are NOT allowed (Library functions are also not allowed but i use it to test first).
I tried to use another function to help und deal all the functions only with recursion. The calculation in the middle was right, but somehow is the output integer not right and I can't get it.

```
unsigned deldigits(unsigned num, unsigned short div)
{   
    if(num == 0) return 0;  

    int digit = num / (digitPower(num)/10);
    int modulo = digit % div;
    printf("ziffer: %d div: %d modulo: %d\n", digit, div, modulo);

    if(digitPower(num) == 0)
            return 0;
    return (digit*10 + deldigits(num - digit*(digitPower(num)/10), div));
}

int digitPower(int n)
{
    if(n == 0) return 1;
    return 10*digitPower(n/10);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned n = 1234;
    unsigned short d = 2;
    int z = deldigits(n, d);
    printf("deldigits:  %d\n", z); 
    return 0;
}
```

The main function is just to test the functions and output. In this occasion, the output must be `13`, but now i got the wrong output `120`. Can someone help me with that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating the problem. You can use

```
num % 10
```

to get the last digit of the number and then check if it is dividable by div. If it is you add it to your answer and up the base with a factor 10 and then remove the digit you just checked by dividing num by 10. Then just repeat until there is no more digits.
Example code:

```
   int recursion(int num,int div,int base) {
      int out = 0;
      if(num) {
        int digit = (num % 10);
        printf("digit %i\n",digit);
        if((digit % div) != 0) {
          out += digit * base;
          base *= 10;
        }
        out += recursion(num/10,div,base);
      }
      return out;
    }
```

Comment: actually we can only use the function like this ```unsigned deldigits(unsigned num, unsigned short div)```, that means an extra int base is also not allowed. I changed ur code without ```int base```on the top and adapted in my code with ```out += digit*10```. Although the output is different than mine but still not the right one.

Comment: would this be allowed for the assignment? unsigned deldigits(unsigned num, unsigned short div) {
  return recursion(num,div,1);
}